# How to send a string that contains comma(,) as an action parameter in caliburn micro?

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I am trying to access a string in my viewmodel.

```
<Image Source="info.png"
    cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseEnter]=[Action MouseOverCallOut('By default, This will be selected')]"/>
```

In my viewmodel, this event is not triggered:

```
public void MouseOverCallOut(string callOutText)
{
  CallOutMsg = callOutText;
}
```

Comment: Here are all available actions that you can use in your parameters: https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions. See `Action Parameters` section. I think you have to rethink your approach and maybe wrap your image into a separate viewmodel.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, ya I read it already that link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you remove the comma (,) from the `string`. This works for me:

```
<Image Source="info.png" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseEnter]=[Action MouseOverCallOut('By defaultThis will be selected')]" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
```

Apparently, `Caliburn.Micro` cannot handle the comma for some reason.

If you definitely need the comma, you could use an invisible `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txt" Text="By default, This will be selected" Visibility="Collapsed" />
<Image Source="info.png" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseEnter]=[Action MouseOverCallOut(txt.Text)]" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
```

Comment: i know that without comma it's work.  i have to show some msg in that comma should be their.